# call blockUI on button onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, blockui

I'm trying to call an blockUI after a buttonclick, but I can't get it to work.
What am I doing wrong?

Script:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function(e) {   
            e.preventDefault();   
            $.blockUI({   
                message: '<div><h1><img src="Images/busy.gif" />   Please wait...</h1>',
                css: { textAlign: 'center', border: '3px solid #aaa', padding: '10px, 0px, 0px, 0px' , verticalalign: 'middle' }  
            }); 
            var btn = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnHidden");
            btn.click();                 
        }); 
    });
```

Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="button" Width="200" />
```

Comment: Is your script in the page directly, and are you getting any JavaScript errors?  Also, you're missing a `</div>` on the message itself.

Comment: Yes, the script and button are in the same child .aspx page. It has a masterpage. But I don't think that can be a problem? The problem is I can't get into the $('#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function(e)...

Comment: Is it in an UpdatePanel perhaps? and make sure you fix the message's closing tag.

Comment: Yes it is, I removed it and it works. But isn't it possible to do it with an updatepanel? Thx already!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're in an UpdatePanel, use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) here, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').live('click', function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();   
        $.blockUI({   
            message: '<div><h1><img src="Images/busy.gif" />   Please wait...</h1></div>',
            css: { textAlign: 'center', border: '3px solid #aaa', padding: '10px, 0px, 0px, 0px' , verticalalign: 'middle' }  
        }); 
        var btn = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnHidden");
        btn.click();                 
    }); 
});
```

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) listens at the `document` level for a click from `btnSave` to bubble up...so it works when the element is added, removed, replaced, etc. (and your UpdatePanel is replacing it each postback), where as [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) attaches *directly* to the element...and that `click` handler is lost when the element is replaced.